# IDE Delphi XE3 Errors in structure

Tags: delphi-xe3

I'm migrating a project from Delphi 7 to Delphi XE3. It works correctly, however in the structure panel, it shows a list of errors:

```
TStringField does not contain a member named AsString
TClientDataSet does not contain a member named CreateDataSet
TList does not contain a member named Add
TToolBar does not contain a member named SetFocus
Undeclared identifier Refresh
Undeclared identifier Handle
TClientDataSet does not contain a member named Post
TPanel does not contain a member named Visible
string does not contain a member named length
string does not contain a member named IndexOf
```

Comment: The structure panel is often wrong. Don't worry about it.

Comment: try to analise your code first, check the errors, read the manual of delphixe3 and make the comparision with delphi xe7. A migration like this requires a full changeable environment to work correctly.